# Wait for previous command to finish while using tee

Tags: command-line, tee

I'm using `tee` as follows:

```
some commands | tee -a >(command1 >> file) >(command2 >> file) >(command3 >> file)
```

How can I delay the execution of command2 till command1 ends, and same for command3 and command2? I tried using `wait` like this, but it didn't work:

```
some commands | tee -a >(command1 >> file) >(wait command2 >> file) >(wait command3 >> file)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is some logic missing along with syntax errors.

`tee -a` will pass output to STDOUT and append simultaneously, no need to use `>`

And why so many output redirects? May be you should utilize `&&` or `;`

Not sure what commands you running but below might give you at least an idea.

```
some commands | tee -a file; command1 >> file; command2 >> file; command3 >> file
```

`some commands | tee -a file` will show STDOUT and write to file, regardless of the exit code, because there is `;` next `command1 >> file` will be executed then command2 and then command3 and so on.

```
some commands | tee -a file; command1 | tee -a file; command2 | tee -a file; command3 | tee -a file
```

Here every command set divided by `;` will be executed in order from left to right and also every command output will be shown in STDOUT